# Problem with elsarticle: Missing } inserted. \end{frontmatter}

Tags: package-management, latex

I am working with elsarticle to write a paper and I have the following problem. The .tex file doesn't compile because of the following problem (along with several others that I assume are because of this one).

```
Missing } inserted. \end{frontmatter}
```

I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400780/error-missing-inserted) which is very similar to my problem, but I am not using the arabtex package.

Do you know how can I solve this problem? (the .tex seems to work in overleaf, this problem is in my Texstudio distribution in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have no solution so far, but some more information that may be useful:

The template distributed by Elsevier only contains `elsarticle.dtx` and `elsarticle.ins` but no `elsarticle.cls`. I tried compiling `elsarticle.dtx` with
`latex elsarticle.dtx`, but I get:

```
! Package doc Error: Checksum not passed (3243<>3244).
```

I also tried to edit elsarticle.dtx changing the checksum to 3244 and recompile. In this case I get no error, but no cls file either (I know very little about compiling dtx files).

So, I assume that when compiling the template, pdflatex is using The version of elsarticle.cls that comes with the texlive distribution, that is

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
```

I have
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)

I have been told that the same template works fine with
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)

So it must be a problem with the newest version of the class file.